# How to serialize/deserialize events in event store and is it so bad to store aggregate roots in them?

Tags: php, domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

I am trying to make CQRS event sourced app in PHP. And I wonder, is it ok to put aggregate root (`AbstractItem` in following example) into event that is serialized in db? (I suppose no, but what is alternative?) For example I have command handler for `AddItemToCartCommand` with this handle method:

```
    public function handle(Command $command)
    {
        Assertion::isInstanceOf($command, AddItemToCartCommand::class);

        $cart = $this->loadCart($command->getCartId());
        $item = $this->loadItem($command->getItemId());

        $cart->addItem($item);

        $this->eventRepository->save($cart);
    }
```

Whereas `Cart` and `AbstractItem` are aggregate roots.
My `Cart` AR is implemented this way:

```
class Cart extends AggregateRoot
{

    /** @var UuidInterface */
    private $customerId;

    /** @var AbstractItem[] */
    private $items;

    public function __construct(UuidInterface $cartId, UuidInterface $customerId)
    {
        $this->apply(new EmptyCartCreated($cartId, $customerId));
    }

    public function addItem(AbstractCartItem $item)
    {
        $this->apply(new ItemToCartAdded($this->getId(), $item));
    }

    protected function applyEmptyCartCreated(EmptyCartCreated $event)
    {
        $this->setId($event->getCartId());
        $this->customerId = $event->getCustomerId();
    }

    protected function applyItemToCartAdded(ItemToCartAdded $event)
    {
        $item                                 = $event->getItem();
        $this->items[(string) $item->getId()] = $item;
    }
}
```

Now, problem is with `ItemToCartAdded` event which has this structure:

```
class ItemToCartAdded extends AbstractDomainEvent
{

    /** @var UuidInterface */
    protected $cartId;

    /** @var AbstractItem */
    protected $item;

    public function __construct(UuidInterface $cartId, AbstractItem $item)
    {
        $this->cartId = $cartId;
        $this->item   = $item;
    }

    public function getCartId(): UuidInterface
    {
        return $this->cartId;
    }

    public function getItem(): AbstractItem
    {
        return $this->item;
    }
}
```

Maybe I should rather have some DTO object to hold `AbstractItem` data instead of `AbstractItem` AR itself in `ItemToCartAdded` event. Then I would in `applyItemToCartAdded` method just instantiate new `AbstractItem` object based on those DTO data.

But since item is abstract class, I dont know what implementation I need to instantiate. Of course I could have class name in that DTO so I know and then somehow hack it. But it seems like little overkill since I have private constructor on `AbstractItem` and use factory methods in specific implementations.

On the other side, serializing whole aggregate root takes me to a problem with serialization: When I serialize AR, I need to deserialize at some point, but how do I do that? I know there is reflection, but it is ugly hack that bypass my AR validation on deserialization and thus I can end up with somehow invalid AR which could fall into nightmare. Or not?

How should I serialize and deserialize my events to solve this problem nicely? Maybe I could have in `ItemToCartAdded` event just ids of those two aggregates, but then I would not be able to apply that event to Cart AR so that it would have list of `AbstractItem`s (to eventually protect some of my invariants). I would end up with just list of item id's in Cart AR, since of course I have not access to repository in my AR.

Where is my problem here or what am I getting wrong?

Btw i use for that fork of this library: https://github.com/beberlei/litecqrs-php

Comment: You could take a look at yet another CQRS+ES library for PHP here https://github.com/xprt64/todosample-cqrs-es In this library events are `yielded` from `Aggregate` then persisted to an `EventStore`. Disclaimer: I've made it :)

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU I checked your framework, btw propagating commands directly into aggregates is interesting aproach, but it takes me to question, should there really be certain AR responsible for every specific command? I think in really most times yes, but really everytime? :)

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU Aggregates yielding events is nice approach, but I cannot see how they should solve my problem :( My problem is, that my Cart AR consists of `AbstractItem` ARs (they can also exist without `Cart`, by themselves) and I need to actually get those into Cart. With your library, I would have similar problem: I would need to add `AbstractItem` AR into `AddItemToCartCommand` (which is nonsense) or it's all data to be able to reinstantiate it in Cart AR handler - which sounds better, but reinstanting AR instead of getting from repository (that is not in AR handler anyway) sounds odd

Comment: Why whould you need to have a handler that uses more than one Aggregate? An Aggregate is the transaction boundary. If you transactionally need to touch more Aggregates in one command then your design is wrong. Yielding Events permitted me to avoid inheritance and keep Aggregates clean, with no dependecies to other layers.

Comment: Every time I see a framework/library that forces me to have any of my **Domain** class inherit from other class I think my **Domain code** whould not be pure anymore. It is ok to use libraries, I use them as often I can, but not for my **Domain code**! Anyway, I avoid `Inheritance` in general and try to use `Composition` instead, with help from `Dependency injection`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to make CQRS event sourced app in PHP. And I wonder, is it ok to put aggregate root (AbstractItem in following example) into event that is serialized in db? (I suppose no, but what is alternative?)

No, you can not. I agree with @Codescribler.
I think that you have a problem with your design.

> Whereas Cart and AbstractItem are aggregate roots.

Why did you make `AbstractItem` an `Aggregate root`? What invariant does `AbstractItem` protects? What `Commands` does it handle and what `Events` yields? This is your main design problem.  And you should name it according to your `Ubiquitous language`, like `Product` or if you need a more abstract name then `CartItem`.

`Product` is an Aggregate root but in a different bounded context, like `Inventory`. Or it could be a CRUD entity if doesn't need to protects any invariants. In that BC it handles the creation, modification and deletion of a product from your store.

You are now in the `Ordering bounded context` and you should review the domain rules in this BC. So, what are your rules? Do you permit a price modification in the `Inventory` BC to be propagated to the items in the `Cart`? I don't think so. Your customers would be very angry, at least no without any notifications that the prices were changed since they added the item to cart. So, let's suppose that once an product was added to the Cart the price freezes. So, it will be immutable.

Now about the `Cart`. What information do you need about the `Products` that are added to the `Cart` in order to protect your **invariants**? What are the `Cart` invariants? Well, you could have a maximum `Order` value, let's say 10000 USD. So you need to identity a `Product` and the `Product price`. 
So, a `CartItem` is a immutable `Value Object`, containing `ProductId` and `ProductPrice`.
So, your code should look like this:

```
namespace Domain\Ordering;

class Cart
{
    /** @var CartItem[] */
    private $items = [];

    const MAXIMUM_CART_VALUE = 10000;

    public function handleAddItemToCart(AddItemToCart $command)
    {
        if ($this->getTotalCartValue() + $command->getItem()->getTotalItemPrice() > self::MAXIMUM_CART_VALUE) {
            throw new \Exception(sprintf("A cart value cannot be more than %d USD", self::MAXIMUM_CART_VALUE));
        }

        yield new AnItemWasAddedToCart($command->getCartId(), $command->getItem());
    }

    public function applyAnItemWasAddedToCart(AnItemWasAddedToCart $event)
    {
        $this->items[] = $event->getItem();
    }

    private function getTotalCartValue()
    {
        return array_reduce($this->items, function (float $acc, CartItem $item) {
            return $acc + $item->getTotalItemPrice();
        }, 0.0);
    }
}

class AddItemToCart implements Command
{

    /**
     * @var CartId
     */
    private $cartId;
    /**
     * @var CartItem
     */
    private $item;

    public function __construct(
        CartId $cartId,
        CartItem $item
    )
    {
        $this->cartId = $cartId;
        $this->item = $item;
    }

    public function getCartId(): CartId
    {
        return $this->cartId;
    }

    public function getItem(): CartItem
    {
        return $this->item;
    }
}

class AnItemWasAddedToCart implements Event
{
    /**
     * @var CartId
     */
    private $cartId;
    /**
     * @var CartItem
     */
    private $item;

    public function __construct(
        CartId $cartId,
        CartItem $item
    )
    {
        $this->cartId = $cartId;
        $this->item = $item;
    }

    public function getCartId(): CartId
    {
        return $this->cartId;
    }

    public function getItem(): CartItem
    {
        return $this->item;
    }
}

class CartId
{
    //...
}

class ProductId
{
    //...
}

class CartItem
{
    /**
     * @var ProductId
     */
    private $productId;
    /**
     * @var float
     */
    private $pricePerUnit;
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $quantity;

    public function __construct(
        ProductId $productId,
        float $pricePerUnit,
        int $quantity
    )
    {
        $this->productId = $productId;
        $this->pricePerUnit = $pricePerUnit;
        $this->quantity = $quantity;
    }

    public function getProductId(): ProductId
    {
        return $this->productId;
    }

    public function getTotalItemPrice()
    {
        return $this->pricePerUnit * $this->quantity;
    }
}
```

Comment: First, customer creates some `AbstractItem` - just sets params of some product or service he wants to order (each of them are our domain and should have its BC for actual handling). This `AbstractItem` has its own invarints implemented in specific classes, for example `CleaningServiceItem` with minimum and maximum length invariant. Then customer adds some of them to cart and checks out. It creates order that has all information about those items. Then customer can use promocode before paying order, which is applied to each item differently, based on it's implementation. How to model this?

Comment: More specifically for example, how do I remove item from cart when it would be value object without id? I still have some link removeItemFromCart?id=SomeUuID on UI in web delivery mechanism, right?

Comment: Even if it is value object you can still refer to the corresponding Aggregate root id. Please observe in my answer that `CartItem` has `productId`.

Comment: Yep, but I somehow do not like that I need another BC for creating entity `AbstractItem` (specification of product/service user is ordering) to be able to use it in current Shop BC as Value Object. Because I have Application service that takes care of creating order from api data, so in that service I need to call every command to compose this "big usecase" - createEmptyCart, createAbstractItem (which should be done in DM of another BC), addAbstractItemToCart and then createOrderFromCart. I think all should be in one BC, because App service of BC1 should not call commands of BC2.

Comment: When you have to send a lot of commands to multiple BCs you need an Saga or ProcessManager that don't in fact belong to any BC. You have two concerns here: Cart creation/updating (more of a UI concern) and Order creation (a Core domain concern). For the Cart you could even use CRUD. For the Order you should use DDD.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer - you don't put an aggregate into an event.

An event represents a change in state. Rather than storing the current state of an aggregate, you capture what changed. This is your event. In your case, the id of the item added would be the minimum info required.  Incidentally, I like to add more info into my events for convenience.

Why is storing an AR in an event bad?

An event is immutable. An AR is by definition mutable. An AR is also encapsulated which makes serialisation at best, awkward.

Comment: Yes, I was suspicious about that. But when I store event with just ID (which is really the only information I theoretically need), I am not able in my applyItemToCartAdded method on cart create whole AbstractItem aggregate which I need to protect some invariants on Cart. Most sense would be to somehow retrieve that AR from repository by ID while applying but since it is obviously nonsense to have repository in AR, I dont know if that has place anywhere on the way, sounds hacky. So am I stuck with actually saving all information about AR and then in apply method take care of instantiating AR?

Comment: I don't know your specific domain but it sounds like you have some modelling work to do. An aggregate root should have all it needs to maintain invariants within the aggregate. Maybe you are missing a concept in your design.

Comment: Or maybe, how about have ARs in events, but on serialization save just their id an on deserialization from event store load them from repository? Is it convenient and common to solve this problem like that? :)

Comment: My opinion - for what it's worth - keep AG out of events! You just don't need them. IMHO

Comment: Yes, that sounds wise I agree. And yes, maybe I missing some concept, because generally, when my AR1 consists of some other AR2, by replaying events on AR1 I should get it in actual state containing AR2. So, I need to have all data I need to create AR2 in events on AR1. That is what sounds weird to me, because then i need to instantiate AR2 that already exists, instead of getting it from repository (that is of course not present in AR1 nor in any AR). Or is it convenient and I should just have some AR2::createFromSomeEventData($d) factory method to reinstantiate AR2 from event?